# Install bower dependencies with single install command

Tags: npm, bower

I'm using bower for the first time and all the documentation I can find shows you how to install one package at a time e.g. "bower install jquery".

I'm used to using npm, where you create a package.json file, add all the dependencies with version numbers and simply run npm install in the same directory and all your dependencies are downloaded in one go.

I want to be able to create a directory containing a website template which somebody can clone and then run a single command which installs all front-end packages with one command into the bower_components folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply create a bower.json file with

```
bower init
```

this will create a file interactively with basic information in the folder you are running this command from. Then, you can add your dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
     ......

  },
```

and install all of them with

```
bower install
```

Comment: Weird, this is only documented on the bower website under "creating packages". Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, as good as bower is, as bad is the documentation on this point... If you don't want to publish your program, make sure to mark it as private in the bower.json creation

Comment: Thanks, I just used bower init to create the file and it made it very easy.